# How to fix mysql access denied on google-cloud-platform compute instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Why my compute engine could not connect MySQL using public IP after I downloaded MySQL-client on my compute instance and I added compute instance's public IP onto CloudSQL authorized connection?

```
$ mysql -h <cloud-sql-host> -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'XXX'@<cloud_sql_host> (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several areas that you must set up to grant access.

**1) Compute Engine Scopes**

Go to the Google Cloud Console for Compute Engine. Double check the scopes that are permitted for the service account for Compute Engine. By default Cloud SQL is not permitted.

**2) Service Account Permissions**

Check is the role that you assigned to service account assigned to Compute Engine. You will need one of the Cloud SQL roles. Usually, you will need `Cloud SQL Client`. The scopes that I previously mentioned serve to reduce and not increase a service account's permissions. You still need to have the correct permissions granted to the service account.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app

**3) Google Cloud SQL database permissions**

Verify that your MySQL login has been "granted" permission to login.

1. Go to the Google Cloud SQL console.
2. Go to the Users tab.
3. Select your user name.
4. Verify that the `host` is your public IP address or optionally use `%` to mean any host.

**Note:** I recommend using the Cloud SQL Proxy to access Cloud SQL. This is secure and you do not need IP addresses for Cloud SQL.

[Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)

Comment: If you use only external IP and connection with MySQL client, the #3 point should be your issue. However, as @johnhanley recommend, Cloud SQL Proxy is recommend for securing the communication (tunneling, SSL by default, no public IP,...) and if you do this, the #1 and #2 point are to take into account.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - You are correct. I tried to provide a broader answer to help with understanding how authorization works and where it is applied.

Answer (score 0):

So for the new Integration Connectors and MySQL I was getting this error:

[28000] Access denied for 'username'@'34.3.56.65'

The resolution was to add the ipaddress 34.3.56.65 to my whitelist list on MySQL Admin on my local control panel.